# Change fragment activity through fragment directly from button Xamarin.Android

Tags: android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-fragmentactivity

I'm using navigation drawer template from `Xamarin` and it working perfectly. So I can change layout dynamically. Now, I need to change fragment directly from single button (like shortcut). Changing between fragments works differently not like simple activity. In activity I can do simple code to change activity through a button:

`Intent nextActivity = new Intent(this, typeof(ItemAddFormActivity));
 StartActivity(nextActivity);`

But, how to change fragment layout from single button? I'm still searching how to change fragment between fragment with button.

Maybe someone here can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to move on another fragment(from fragment) on button click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i have implemented in my solution, might help you

this is my fragment

```
   public class Fragment3 : Fragment
{
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your fragment here
    }

    public static Fragment3 NewInstance()
    {
        var frag1 = new Fragment3 { Arguments = new Bundle() };
        return frag1;
    }


    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {         
        var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment3, null);       
    }
}
```

To Display Fragment on button event use this

```
Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment = null;
fragment = Fragment3.NewInstance();

 if (fragment == null)
            return;

       SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
          .Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment)
          .Commit();
```

Comment: I'll try first if that code work or not.. 
Just put this code on button event?
thanks :)

Comment: I tried that code.. that code works on activity but not from fragmentactivity

Comment: @YeremiaDanang can you share what error you getting  ?

Comment: @RonakShetia I don't get any error, I just want change layout from fragment to another fragment :)

Comment: i have the same scenario and it works for me, people can help you if you share some more code or the things which you have tried